# Reordenar as categorias em um data frame

Tags: r, data.frame, factors

Quando importamos dados no R ele ordena as categorias por ordem alfabética. Como fazer para alterar essa ordem?

Suponha que sejam os seguintes dados:

```
df <- data.frame(categorias=c("Muito baixa","Baixa","Média","Alta","Muito alta"),
                 valores=seq(1:5))

> levels(df$categorias)
[1] "Alta"        "Baixa"       "Média"       "Muito alta"  "Muito baixa"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao criar o `factor`, você pode dizer ao `R` qual a ordem que você quer para os `levels`:

```
df$categorias <- factor(df$categorias, levels=c("Muito baixa","Baixa","Média","Alta","Muito alta")
```

Resultado:

```
levels(df$categorias)
[1] "Muito baixa" "Baixa"       "Média"       "Alta"        "Muito alta"
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra alternativa para alterar a sua ordem:

```
levels(df$categorias)=levels(df$categorias)[c(5,2,3,1,4)]
levels(df$categorias)

[1] "Muito baixa" "Baixa"       "Média"       "Alta"        "Muito alta"
```